# Unkillable process after connection loss to samba share

Tags: centos, samba, server-message-block

Using [this](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/WindowsShares) manual I've mounted samba share. I'm copying files to it using python script.

Everything is working fine until some problem with network occurs. After that I get unkillable process in "D" state. Furthermore, even standard programs like ls can faint and become unkillable if used on mounted share. The only solution is to change path in config files of automount, restart automount service and use new path. But unkillable processes are still there, of course.

So, the question is: how to avoid this situation?